# How to patch a page using the new OneNote Ink Beta Apis

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

As per this page
 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/onenotedev/2017/07/07/onenote-ink-beta-apis/
It is possible to get ink from a OneNote page and to create a page with ink.
How does one go about patching the body of a page to add ink?
I have tried via a page PATCH

```
'content':'<inkml data-render-src="name:presentation-onenote-inkml"/>'
```

without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, PATCHing with InkML is not supported by the OneNote API at this point.

https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/245490-onenote-developer-apis

I encourage you to enter an ask for us in uservoice.

Comment: Thanks Jorge. Obviously this would be a useful feature! My current workaround will be to extract the current ink data, append the new data, regenerate the page and then delete the old page.